# Is it logical to use async resolve ever?

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

I am new to Promises, so I am wondering if this is fine:

```
this.someFunc()
  .then(() => {
    alert('loaded')
  });

someFunc() = () => {
  return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
    let obj = await AsyncStorage.getItem('some_val');

    //do stuff with obj

    resolve('yay, everything's done');
  });
};
```

Or should I always ALWAYS use `then` with Promises like

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('some_val')
   .then((obj) => {
      // do stuff with obj
      resolve('yay')
   });
```

? Is the first approach anti-pattern like? Is it "wrong"? And why?

Comment: You don't need the (manually created) promise at all. Just take your first example, make the function async, remove the `new Promise` stuff and `return` instead of `resolve`.

Comment: @tkausl The problem is if I don't return anything, ``` .then(() => { alert('loaded') });``` is done even without code completing in someFunc (I am doing there some requests with fetch())

Comment: A async function implicitly returns a promise which will be resolved to the value you return.

Comment: If I don't return anything, it gets resolved anyway. That's my problem. I think I am not understanding something. I use fetch and `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` in that async function too btw.

Comment: Well lets put it this way: It will get resolved if you either return something or the function returns by other means (at the closing `}`), which is the same behavior you've got in your example snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `async` keyword to a function makes it return a Promise.

Ignoring that promise and wrapping it in another one doesn't really make sense. It makes the code confusing to people trying to maintain it.

You could rewrite it as:

```
someFunc() = async () => {
    let obj = await AsyncStorage.getItem('some_val');

    //do stuff with obj

    return 'yay, everything's done';
};
```

Comment: The problem is if I don't return anything, ```  .then(() => {
    alert('loaded')
  });``` is done even without code completing in `someFunc` (I am doing there some requests with `fetch()`)

Comment: @good_evening — I can't reproduce that problem: http://jsbin.com/lisivifeju/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I use `fetch()` inside of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`

Comment: @good_evening — Which is an async function, so you would need to promisify *that*

Comment: You mean I would need to wrap it in Promise class?

Comment: @good_evening — You'd need to wrap getCurrentPosition in a promise so you can await it.

Answer (score 0):

I just refactored your codes by removing unnecessary things.

```
someFunc() = async () => { 
// when you declare arrow function, it should not have () with its name
// put async before arguments to enable await in the code block below 

 return new Promise(async(resolve) => { 
 // you don't need this line because of async and await
 // await returns data wrapped by Promise 
 // as soon as this Promise is resolved or rejected 

   let obj = await AsyncStorage.getItem('some_val'); 
   // 'await' will return the item that is wrapped by Promise. 
   // So, you can access the item(the returned data) in this code block. 
   // but if you want this 'someFunc' to return 'obj'

   //do stuff with obj

   resolve("yay, everything's done");
   // you don't need this line because 'await' will take care of
   // 'AsyncStorage.getItem('some_val')'
 });
};
```

After refactoring, you will have code like below.

```
someFunc = async () => { 
  // One of the benefit of async and await is that you can use try/catch block.
  // So, you can easily console out error without by chaining multiple '.catch' after 
  // every '.then'.
  try{
    let obj = await AsyncStorage.getItem('some_val');
    // 'obj' will be the value of item 'some_val'

    // do stuff with obj 
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return obj; //this will return resolved Promise because of await.
};
```

If you want to use this obj in another function, you can do something like below.

```
anotherFunc = async () => {
  try{
    const resolvedObj = await someFunc(); 
    // Since someFunc will return resolved Promise that wraps the data from
    // AsyncStorage, await will assign the data to 'resolvedObj'
    // However, if you return 'resolvedObj', this will be 'Promise {<resolved>: 
    // dataFromAsyncStorage}'

    // do stuff with 'resolvedObj'

  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);      
  }
}
```